# Excel VBS Mass Mailing Multiple Attachments

Tags: vba, email, excel, vbscript

I wrote a VBA script to send emails to an arbitrary number of contacts from an excel file. The excel file basically has a column of email address's and attachment's, where attachment's is the name of the file to attach to the email. What I want to do is be able to add multiple attachments, by separating each attachment by `;` in the attachments column and making the script go on to add the next attachment. The trouble I am having is I don't know how to do it without setting a fixed number of attachments for contacts. The scenario I am trying to capture is, one contact can have 3 attachments, another one could have 2 and another 0 attachments.

Comment: So **what is your specific question**?

Comment: In my attachment's col, I want to add multiple files, and I want to separate it with a `;` so like, `file1.pdf;file2.pdf` for one contact, another may have no files to add.

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split a text in a cell to an array, then just loop through the array.

```
Const DELIMITER = ";"

Dim strCellText as String, strAttachment as String 
Dim strAttachments() As String

strCellText = 'load your cell text here

strAttachments = Split(strCellText, DELIMITER)

For Each strAttachment In strAttachments 
  'attach an attachment to a mail
Next
```